# How to create a reuseable page in Windows Phone project?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

It's a pain to create a about page everytime I create a new windows phone app. Although I can copy & paste the existing code, but when I modify one page, I should copy and paste to the rest. A huge time wasting.

**What I want:**

1. A reusable page. (not a Advanced MessageBox)
2. The reusable resource should accept 2 parameters. one is the app title and one is
   the version number.
3. Should be compatible with Windows Phone OS 7.1 (Mango)

I know something called User Control, but it seems that it can only be create inside a project. @_@

So, How to fulfill my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the same I hate copying and pasting pages. I personally love using YLAD, (Your Last About Dialogue) it's fantastically made, is very professional, and is very easy to simply input your information. Available from NuGet or download from [this link](http://ylad.codeplex.com/).